# Weekday function in is showing incorrect days

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to generate the day of the week for each day between 2013 and 2015. I have used the following code from the lubridate package. + 3 has been used to start at Tuesday as the 1st Jan 2013 is a Tuesday.

```
df$Day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$Date)+3)
```

However the dates are correct at the start of 2013 but further on the day does not match the date. Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Please provide reproducible data. We dont have any info about `df`.

Answer (score 0):

`weekdays` expects argument of type `class "POSIXt" or "Date"`. Moreover, function is vectorized as well, meaning if you pass a vector containing `Date` then a vector will be returned with week days.

i.e. The below code generates a vector from `2013/01/01` to `2015/12/31` and then converts weekdays for each day.

```
 library(lubridate)
 weekdays(seq(ymd("2013/01/01"), ymd("2015/12/31"), by="day"))
 #[1] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday" 
 # ....so on
```

Please note in output above that `weekdays` for dates starting from `2013/01/01` on wards has been evaluated and displayed.